# Updating a desktop application without touching the attached .mdf

Tags: c#, winforms

Just a quick question:

I'm in the finalizing state of my current C# project, and I'd like to send a version out to people that has 90% of the features initially requested, but it'll be a version of the software that will do all they need - they need the software as soon as possible, basically.

Therefore I'm going to be using the online install option in VS2008 that will use updating to add the final few features, as well as additional things, later. What I'm wondering is the following:

The program will come packaged with a .mdf file. When I create a new version of the program however, I don't want to change all of the data that has been added to the database already. My question is how do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you planning to distribute the update?  An installer will have flags indicating when a file should be replaced.  (Date, version etc)

One-Click installation has the ability to check for changes on program startup.

Comment: Planning to distribute the updates online, checking via version number. Where in the properties are these options?

Comment: Which installer are you using?

Comment: Just the default one provided by VS2008 when using one-click installation.

Comment: Have you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28VS.80%29.aspx ?  My installs haven't needed individual file updates yet, so I haven't fought the battle (yet)